# How do I merge these dataframes and take the column means?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, mean

I have merged these two dataframes, and I want to take the mean of the columns and combine them into one dataframe. Here is my dataframe merged:

```
           ARN     ADOPTION.x    EUTHANASIA.x     OTHER.x           ADOPTION.y     EUTHANASIA.y     OTHER.y
99645 A1428364 0.998701572418 0.0000001962661 0.001298154    0.990897715091705 0.00000014520751 0.009102128
99646 A1428368 0.000122911530 0.9927836656570 0.007093379  0.00270643248222768 0.00152872898616 0.995764852
99647 A1428369 0.978477597237 0.0000004987147 0.021521868    0.933309495449066 0.00000007226861 0.066690445
99648 A1428370 0.004124862142 0.8476260900497 0.148249015 0.000234879378695041 0.87564605474472 0.124119066
99649 A4081681 0.464215517044 0.0024338855874 0.533350587    0.699311196804047 0.04458642378449 0.256102324
99650 A4087524 0.000006879755 0.0021564548369 0.997836649 0.000240802211919799 0.00144882441964 0.998310328
```

I want to, for example, take the average of each column of adoption.x + adoption.y and just make the column "adoption." Then repeat for each column. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: do you really want to merge them? or is it better to use rbind(df1,df2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Hadleyverse version:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

       # melt data into long form
df %>% gather(var, val, -ARN) %>% 
    # separate suffixes into new column
    separate(var, c('var', 'origin')) %>% 
    # spread back to wide form
    spread(var, val) %>% 
    # set grouping for aggregation
    group_by(ARN) %>% 
    # aggregate each variable within each group
    summarise_each(funs(mean), -origin)

# Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
# 
#        ARN    ADOPTION   EUTHANASIA       OTHER
#     (fctr)       (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)
# 1 A1428364 0.994799644 1.707368e-07 0.005200141
# 2 A1428368 0.001414672 4.971562e-01 0.501429116
# 3 A1428369 0.955893546 2.854917e-07 0.044106157
# 4 A1428370 0.002179871 8.616361e-01 0.136184040
# 5 A4081681 0.581763357 2.351015e-02 0.394726456
# 6 A4087524 0.000123841 1.802640e-03 0.998073488
```

---

Note that instead of merging, it would be much easier to group by an ID column, row bind, and aggregate, i.e.

```
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
    group_by(ARN) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

or in base R

```
aggregate(. ~ ARN, rbind(df1, df2), mean)
```

or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(rbind(df1, df2))[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = ARN]
```

---

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(ARN = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A1428364", "A1428368", 
    "A1428369", "A1428370", "A4081681", "A4087524"), class = "factor"), 
        ADOPTION.x = c(0.998701572418, 0.00012291153, 0.978477597237, 
        0.004124862142, 0.464215517044, 6.879755e-06), EUTHANASIA.x = c(1.962661e-07, 
        0.992783665657, 4.987147e-07, 0.8476260900497, 0.0024338855874, 
        0.0021564548369), OTHER.x = c(0.001298154, 0.007093379, 0.021521868, 
        0.148249015, 0.533350587, 0.997836649), ADOPTION.y = c(0.990897715091705, 
        0.00270643248222768, 0.933309495449066, 0.000234879378695041, 
        0.699311196804047, 0.000240802211919799), EUTHANASIA.y = c(1.4520751e-07, 
        0.00152872898616, 7.226861e-08, 0.87564605474472, 0.04458642378449, 
        0.00144882441964), OTHER.y = c(0.009102128, 0.995764852, 
        0.066690445, 0.124119066, 0.256102324, 0.998310328)), .Names = c("ARN", 
    "ADOPTION.x", "EUTHANASIA.x", "OTHER.x", "ADOPTION.y", "EUTHANASIA.y", 
    "OTHER.y"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

df1 <- structure(list(ARN = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A1428364", "A1428368", 
    "A1428369", "A1428370", "A4081681", "A4087524"), class = "factor"), 
        ADOPTION = c(0.998701572418, 0.00012291153, 0.978477597237, 
        0.004124862142, 0.464215517044, 6.879755e-06), EUTHANASIA = c(1.962661e-07, 
        0.992783665657, 4.987147e-07, 0.8476260900497, 0.0024338855874, 
        0.0021564548369), OTHER = c(0.001298154, 0.007093379, 0.021521868, 
        0.148249015, 0.533350587, 0.997836649)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("ARN", "ADOPTION", "EUTHANASIA", 
    "OTHER"))

df2 <- structure(list(ARN = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A1428364", "A1428368", 
    "A1428369", "A1428370", "A4081681", "A4087524"), class = "factor"), 
        ADOPTION = c(0.990897715091705, 0.00270643248222768, 0.933309495449066, 
        0.000234879378695041, 0.699311196804047, 0.000240802211919799
        ), EUTHANASIA = c(1.4520751e-07, 0.00152872898616, 7.226861e-08, 
        0.87564605474472, 0.04458642378449, 0.00144882441964), OTHER = c(0.009102128, 
        0.995764852, 0.066690445, 0.124119066, 0.256102324, 0.998310328
        )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("ARN", 
    "ADOPTION", "EUTHANASIA", "OTHER"))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can subset the columns that end with `.x` and `.y` and take the mean

```
d1 <- (df1[grep("\\.x$", names(df1))] + df1[grep("\\.y$", names(df1))])/2
colnames(d1) <- c("ADOPTION",   "EUTHANASIA", "OTHER")
d2 <- cbind(df1["ARN"], d1)
d2
#        ARN    ADOPTION      EUTHANASIA       OTHER
#99645 A1428364 0.994799644 0.0000001707368 0.005200141
#99646 A1428368 0.001414672 0.4971561973216 0.501429116
#99647 A1428369 0.955893546 0.0000002854917 0.044106157
#99648 A1428370 0.002179871 0.8616360723972 0.136184040
#99649 A4081681 0.581763357 0.0235101546859 0.394726456
#99650 A4087524 0.000123841 0.0018026396283 0.998073488
```

Or another option would be to `melt` to long format and then convert to 'wide' with `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dM <- melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns("\\.x$", "\\.y$"), value.name = 
       c("x", "y"))[, variable := c("ADOPTION",   "EUTHANASIA", "OTHER")[variable]
       ][, .(ARN, variable, value = (x+y)/2)]
dcast(dM, ARN~variable, value.var="value")
#      ARN    ADOPTION      EUTHANASIA       OTHER
#1: A1428364 0.994799644 0.0000001707368 0.005200141
#2: A1428368 0.001414672 0.4971561973216 0.501429116
#3: A1428369 0.955893546 0.0000002854917 0.044106157
#4: A1428370 0.002179871 0.8616360723972 0.136184040
#5: A4081681 0.581763357 0.0235101546859 0.394726456
#6: A4087524 0.000123841 0.0018026396283 0.998073488
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation on the long format + aggregate method suggested by @akrun:

```
datlong <- reshape(dat, idvar="ARN", sep=".", direction="long", varying=-1)
nms <- names(datlong)[-c(1,2)]
datlong$seq <- with(datlong, ave(time,time,FUN=seq_along) )
aggregate(datlong[nms], datlong[c("ARN","seq")], FUN=mean)[-2]

#       ARN    ADOPTION   EUTHANASIA       OTHER
#1 A1428364 0.994799644 1.707368e-07 0.005200141
#2 A1428368 0.001414672 4.971562e-01 0.501429116
#3 A1428369 0.955893546 2.854917e-07 0.044106157
#4 A1428370 0.002179871 8.616361e-01 0.136184040
#5 A4081681 0.581763357 2.351015e-02 0.394726456
#6 A4087524 0.000123841 1.802640e-03 0.998073488
```